# Equatiomatic notation includes fixed effect slope in the distribution of a random effect intercept

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models, equatiomatic

The vignette for {equatiomatic} includes the following example ([here](https://datalorax.github.io/equatiomatic/articles/lme4-lmer.html#models-with-predictors-at-level-1)):

```
library(lme4)
library(equatiomatic)

lev1_long <- lmer(score ~ wave + (1|sid) + (1|school) + (1|district),
                  data = sim_longitudinal)
extract_eq(lev1_long)
```

which results in the resulting notation:

[image]

The different random intercepts get denoted each in their own line (I presume it is implicit that they are added together to generate the combined intercept?) and the fixed slope for `wave`, denoted as $\beta_1$, gets included in the first line, in the distribution of the outcome variable `score`. I can reproduce this example successfully.

However when I work with some data that I think has a very similar structure, I get a different notation. Here is a reproducible example with a dummy dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(equatiomatic)

mock_df <- tibble(
  outcome = 1:10,
  oID = c('D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'C'),
  treatment =  rep(c(0, 1), each = 5),
  pID = c('P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3', 'P4', 'P4'))

model <- lmer(outcome ~ 1 + treatment + (1|pID) + (1|oID), data = mock_df)
extract_eq(model)
```

Of course, the model is completely inadequate for the made-up data, but ignore that for a moment. The {equatiomatic} output is:

[image]

Just like in the vignette example, we have multiple random intercepts and one fixed slope. But the equation looks quite different. The slope has been moved to the third line, into the distribution of the random intercept for `pID`.

I do not really understand the reason for this difference in notation, or, for that matter, why the slope went into the distribution for the `pID` intercept rather than the `oID` intercept. Is there some actual fundamental difference in model structure between the example in the vignette and the made-up mock example I made that justifies the difference in notation?

Comment: Hi Gil, I have the feeling you should put this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you Stephan! Sorry for misplacing the question. I initially thought of this as an R question rather than a stats question, but I suppose you're correct. I'll move the question and delete it from here.

Comment: you can leave it here, I assume the moderators will take care of it. Its just I think math/stats can help you more than coders with this. But a vast majority use both platforms. Maybe search a stats tag?

Answer (score 2):

This illustrates why the `lmer` formula is not sufficient to specify the mixed effect model. We also have to state, for each fixed predictor, whether it describes the individuals or the groups.

Notice how in your mock data treatment doesn't vary within pIDs because treatment is assigned to pIDs, not to individuals; all individuals with the same pID label have the same treatment.

```r
mock_df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    outcome oID   treatment pID  
#>      <int> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>
#>  1       1 D             0 P1   
#>  2       2 A             0 P1   
#>  3       3 B             0 P2   
#>  4       4 C             0 P2   
#>  5       5 B             0 P2   
#>  6       6 B             1 P3   
#>  7       7 E             1 P3   
#>  8       8 B             1 P3   
#>  9       9 A             1 P4   
#> 10      10 C             1 P4
```

We can summarize this observation by counting treatment assigments by pID. For comparison we also count treatment assignments by oID.

```r
treatment_by_group <- function(df, group) {
  df %>%
    count(treatment, {{ group }}) %>%
    pivot_wider(
      names_from = treatment,
      values_from = n,
      values_fill = 0L
    )
}

treatment_by_group(mock_df, pID)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   pID     `0`   `1`
#>   <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1 P1        2     0
#> 2 P2        3     0
#> 3 P3        0     3
#> 4 P4        0     2
treatment_by_group(mock_df, oID)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   oID     `0`   `1`
#>   <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1 A         1     1
#> 2 B         2     2
#> 3 C         1     1
#> 4 D         1     0
#> 5 E         0     1
```

Since treatment assignment doesn't vary within pIDs, we cannot learn about the differences between treatments by comparing individuals within pIDs; we have to compare pIDs instead.

This nesting of individuals within pIDs makes the model hierarchical. Effectively, the model has two components: a regression for each pID and then a regression for each observation given its pID. That's exactly what you see in the *equatiomatic* model specification.

Contrast the grouping by pID with the grouping by oID. We can estimate the difference between treatments by comparing individuals within oIDs (more precisely, by comparing individuals in the `A`, `B` and `C` oIDs).

PS: I wrote a longer explanation, with more formulas, in response to this Cross Validation question: [Writing mathematical equations (mixed effect models)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/580157/writing-mathematical-equations-mixed-effect-models)

Comment: Thank you so much for your very clear answer (and for the link to the great explanation with formulas). When I changed the mock data so that we can have the same pID associated with different treatments, the {equatiomatic} notation indeed changed. However, confusingly, the change consisted of moving the effect of treatment from the pID distribution into the oID distribution. Based on your answer, I would not expect this, since each oID can have different treatments (e.g., oID B can have treatment 0 or 1). I thought I had understood, but there is still something I don't get.

Comment: That's not I observe if I drop pID on mock_df: *lmer(outcome ~ 1 + treatment + (1 | oID), data = mock_df)*. The hierarchical structure depends on how random effects are nested and/or crossed. It can get a bit complicated. Here is a nice explanation: [Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified).

Comment: Note that the hierarchical structure doesn't change *E{Y}*, just the standard errors on the fixed effects estimates. Because it's harder to estimate a fixed effect from *k* groups than from *n > k* individuals.